# Какую технологию/возможность/средство QT использовать для отображения 2D графика

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Необходимо отобразить 2D график (до 5 млн. вещественных точек) в виде кривой.

Какое средство из Qt подойдёт в плане производительности для отрисовки ?

подумываю применить `QGraphicsView` вместе с `QGraphicsScene` но не уверен насчёт возможностей и быстроты рендеринга

используется ли там аппаратное ускорение ?

или рендерится на CPU side ?

конечно, в качестве лобого варианта можно напрямую рендерить график через `raw OpenGL API`

но хотелось бы не переусердствовать, и не переусложнять всё, а обойтись оптимальным решением.

**p.s.**

готовые варианты/компоненты заточенные для отображения графиков не рассматриватся вообще, поэтому их не предлагать

Comment: А чем вас Qt Charts не подходят?

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко ну я же отметил, что готовые компоненты не рассматриваются, зачем предлагать ?

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко да и неясно по производительности что там происходит

Comment: не думаю, что вы напишите лучше, чем написали профессиональные разработчики Qt Charts, и если вы так уж гонитесь за производительностью(вероятно для спутника пишите), то тогда уж на чистом С пишите. По своему опыту могу сказать, что графическая сцена вполне пригодна для большого кол-ва элементов, но лучше рисовать в потоке без всяких буферных QPixmap`ов, последний очень жрущий оперативку зверь.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко здесь не стоит вопрос, о том, что я напишу лучше  чем разрабы Qt Charts, мой вопрос довольно конкретный и самодостаточный. по поводу QGraphicsScene вы говорите, что он вполне  может отобразить большое кол-во точек, но насколько большое ? и использует ли оно OpenGL для рендеринга ? c qt я знаком достаточно поверхностно, потому и спрашиваю

Comment: Ну я полагаю, что openGL, хотя что там подключается под виндой я не знаю, ну а что мешает взять и сгенерить тебе эти 3кк точек? это не сложно.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко так вот если не знаешь тогда пожалуйста, оставь это дело, да и запускатья будет не только под windows, а точек не 3кк (я не знаю как это проинтерпретировать, тысячи чтоли? ) а до 5 миллионов, которые не генерируются а читаются из файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта я думаю:

1. QOpenGLWidget
2. QGraphicsView заставить выводить на OpenGL, где-то читал, что в этом случае от быстродействия останется 40%, но это всё равно хорошо

Comment: что значит от быстродействия останется 40%, увеличится на 40% или уменьшится ??

Comment: и кстати я так и сделал пока, использую QGraphicsScene - а opengl включил вот так - `ui->graphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget());`

Comment: в смысле, будет медленне чем чистый OpenGL

Comment: для Qt5 лучше использовать QOpenGLWidget, QGLWidget - устарел

Comment: тоесть с включённым opengl как я сделал будет быстрее на 40% ?

Comment: вобщем написал код отрисовки с помощью `QGraphicsView` и `QGraphicsScene` но что-то сильно тормозит рендеринг даже для 1 ого миллиона точек - где то гигабайт оперативной памяти уходит на рендеринг, странно это с включённым`OpenGL` - попробую  `QOpenglWidget` и ручное управление буферами для вывода - тут уж  точно не уйдёт столько рама